# Adding to a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Suppose someone offers a bounty and i want to increase that bounty - is there a way to do that? If not is it possible to set it up that others can increase a bounty.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68416/techum-of-new-york currently has a bounty. I would love to add to this bounty. Perhaps it is time to revisit this question.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible at the moment, no: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties says that to set a bounty on a question, it can't already have one. As for the feature request, it's been asked before, both [as an idea of adding to someone else's bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2261) and [as an idea of having two users post simultaneous independent bounties on a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64768). I don't see that any real answer was offered to the latter question, though. (When you read the adding-to-another's-bounty question, bear in mind that it was written during a time that one could offer a bounty only on his own question.)

Comment: I actually wanted to add to the bounty you added to  Why, in double parshiyos, are the aliyos not simply combined in pairs? as I feel it is a great question and I am curious if anyone can find someone who addresses it.